# How can I convert a List<GameObject> to Transform[] array?

Tags: unity, c#

```
var selection = Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().ToList();
tempTransforms = selection;
```

selection is List and tempTransform is Transform[]
And I want to assign the selection to the tempTransform.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `tempTransforms = Selection.transforms`?

Comment: @Jimmy: I forgot that was an option! I think that would be a better answer than what I wrote below, if you'd care to post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple C# syntax questions that don't require game development expertise, [don't forget to search our general programming sister site StackOverflow first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068120/c-sharp-cast-entire-array) - they'll often have more coverage of topics like these.

```
// Store intermediate selection as an array so we can use the ConvertAll method.
var selection = Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().ToArray();

// Provide a lambda to look up the corresponding Transform, given a GameObject.
tempTransform = Array.ConvertAll(selection, item => item.transform);
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to get an array of `Transform`s from the selection is

```
tempTransform = Selection.transforms;
```